# String replace character with backslash and double quote in a column of an R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, stringr

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1", "2", "3"),
  option_json = c('{"thickness":"0.031 inches","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}', '{"thickness":"0.031 inches","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}' , '{"tensile strength":"600 lb","color":"Black","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}'))
```

```
  ID                                                                              option_json
1  1 {"thickness":"0.031 inches","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}
2  2 {"thickness":"0.031 inches","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}
3  3            {"tensile strength":"600 lb","color":"Black","size":"0.5 Inches x 7200 Feet"}
```

I want this dataframe:

```
  ID                                                                option_json
1  1 {"thickness":"0.031\"","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
2  2 {"thickness":"0.031\"","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
3  3       {"tensile strength":"600 lb","color":"Black","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
```

I tried using str_replace and gsub to replace the inches but I keep getting double backslashes behind the double quote. Not sure how to just string replace with just a single backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in R, they will always print two backslashes together if one of them are escaped. When two backslashes are shown together, it is only a syntax to show that these should be interpreted as a character "\" but not an escape character.

To confirm that, you can try to save your dataframe to a text file, you will see that there's actually only one backslash in the string.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(option_json = gsub(" inches", '\\\\"', option_json, ignore.case = T) %>% 
                      gsub(" Feet", "\\'", ., ignore.case = T))

write.table(df, "df.tsv", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

### Output copied from "df.tsv"

```
ID option_json
1 {"thickness":"0.031\"","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
2 {"thickness":"0.031\"","tensile strength":"600 lb","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
3 {"tensile strength":"600 lb","color":"Black","size":"0.5\" x 7200'"}
```

### Try printing the "option_json" column

You can see that before every double quote `"` character, there is a escape character `\`. And `\\` is used to indicate a single `\` character.

```
print(df$option_json)
[1] "{\"thickness\":\"0.031\\\"\",\"tensile strength\":\"600 lb\",\"size\":\"0.5\\\" x 7200'\"}"
[2] "{\"thickness\":\"0.031\\\"\",\"tensile strength\":\"600 lb\",\"size\":\"0.5\\\" x 7200'\"}"
[3] "{\"tensile strength\":\"600 lb\",\"color\":\"Black\",\"size\":\"0.5\\\" x 7200'\"}"
```